# JPA: hashmap from entity to entity gets wrong primary keys in join table

Tags: java, sql, jpa, dictionary, eclipselink

I am trying to model the following:
Students can take part in exams and get grades.
It should be possible to assign the same grade entity to multiple students.
The grades are stored inside a map (in the 'Exam' class) which is annotated like this:

```
@ManyToMany
@MapKeyClass(value = Person.class)
@JoinTable(name = "t1")
private Map<Person, Grade> grades;
```

JPA creates the following join table:

```
T1:  
EXAM_ID: stores the id of the exam, is part of the primary key  
GRADES_ID: stores the id of the grade, is part of the primary key  
GRADES_KEY: stores the id of the student, is not part of the primary key
```

However the table I expected would have a primary key consiting of the student and the exam.
The problem im facing now is when I try the following:

```
grades.put(student1, grade1);
grades.put(student2, grade1);
```

... I will get an exception telling me im violating the database constraints.
How do I properly persist this map?

I'm using eclipselink 2.6.0 as JPA provider. The application is running on a glassfish server with a derby database.

Thank you for reading and have a nice day :)

UPDATE:
These are the SQL queries, eclipselink calls to create the database:

```
...
CREATE TABLE EXAM_GRADE (Exam_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, grades_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, grades_KEY BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (Exam_ID, grades_ID))
...
ALTER TABLE EXAM_GRADE ADD CONSTRAINT EXAMGRADEgrades_ID FOREIGN KEY (grades_ID) REFERENCES GRADE (ID)
ALTER TABLE EXAM_GRADE ADD CONSTRAINT EXAMGRADEgradesKEY FOREIGN KEY (grades_KEY) REFERENCES PERSON (ID)
ALTER TABLE EXAM_GRADE ADD CONSTRAINT EXAM_GRADE_Exam_ID FOREIGN KEY (Exam_ID) REFERENCES EXAM (ID)
...
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve your problem? I am having exactly the same problem with map/primary keys/etc...

Comment: Hi Thomas, I can't recall exactly how, but I worked around the problem by restructuring my data.

Comment: Hi Niko, thanks for your reply, not the one I wanted to hear though :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have got a couple of problems here: I tried it on Hibernate and got different results from you. I think Hibernate is doing it correctly, thus my first answer up to the UPDATE.

Firstly, the code that you show shouldn't produce the results that you are getting. When you claim that `GRADES_ID` is part of the `primary key` in the `join table`, that should not be true. When I run the example, I get `primary key (Exam_id, grades_KEY)`.

Secondly, you should have a `OneToMany` relationship, not a `ManyToMany` relationship in your `grades` field. Having a `ManyToMany` relationship should not cause a `constraint violation` when you insert the same grade for two students. When you have a `OneToMany` relation then a `constraint` for `unique (grades_id)` will be created, which would indeed prevent you from inserting the same grade for two students:

```
grades.put(student1, grade1);
grades.put(student2, grade1);
```

Having the `constraint` is preferable because it would prevent a coding error where one student's grade is also assigned to another student.

When you are thinking of relationships, think of the relationship between the `Entities`. In this case you have One `Exam` and Many `Students`, so you should have a `OneToMany`.

Finally, the `MapKeyClass` is redundant, and there is no good reason to name your `join table` yourself, especially as `t1`.

Your relationship should be simple:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<Student, Grade> grades;
```

When you create an `Exam`, be sure you save unique grades to each student:

```
public void testCreateExam() {
    Student student1 = new Student("Karl");
    Grade grade1 = new Grade(85);
    Student student2 = new Student("Debbie");
    Grade grade2 = new Grade(90);
    Map<Student, Grade> grades = new HashMap<Student, Grade>();
    grades.put(student1, grade1);
    grades.put(student2, grade2);
    examService.createExam("Biology", grades);
}
```

and be sure you persist each `Student` and `Grade` first (or work out appropriate logic):

```
public Exam createExam(String name, Map<Student, Grade> grades) {
    for(Student student: grades.keySet()) {
        em.persist(student);
        Grade grade = grades.get(student);
        em.persist(grade);
    }
    Exam exam = new Exam(name);
    exam.setGrades(grades);
    em.persist(exam);
    return exam;
}
```

UPDATE:

I looked at EclipseLink 2.6. Wow, totally FUBAR. Firstly, it wouldn't even let me annotate a Map with `OneToMany`, which is just plain wrong. Secondly, it handled the `ManyToMany` exactly the way I described Hibernate as handling the `OneToMany`. So, I got the `Eclipselink` version to work the way `Hibernate` did with the `ManyToMany`, but I had to generate the Schema scripts, change them by hand, and use them to create the database going forward. Hardly a good way to develop code.

```
// Change the primary key to be the Exam_Id and the grades_KEY
CREATE TABLE EXAM_GRADE (Exam_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, grades_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, grades_KEY BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (Exam_ID, grades_KEY))
// removed the constraint for grades_ID references GRADE (ID)
ALTER TABLE EXAM_GRADE ADD CONSTRAINT EXAMGRADEgradesKEY FOREIGN KEY (grades_KEY) REFERENCES PERSON (ID)
ALTER TABLE EXAM_GRADE ADD CONSTRAINT EXAM_GRADE_Exam_ID FOREIGN KEY (Exam_ID) REFERENCES EXAM (ID)
```

I was able to write and read the same `Grade` for a different `Student` after I made these changes. These schema scripts are now exactly the way Hibernate generates them. I think something went funny over at Eclipselink, and it is a good idea to submit a bug on this. Also, note, while you may want to assign the same grade to different students, it doesn't make sense in the problem domain, but of course that's my humble opinion. I realize that a Java `Map` will be able to have different `keys` refer to the same `value`, so it's certainly a conceivable requirement for some problems, which `Ecpliselink` does not seem to be able to handle.

Comment: I want to be able to assign the same grade to multiple students, that is why im using the ManyToMany. This is why the weird primary keys constraints are causing problems. May I asked which JPA Provider and which version you used?

Comment: I'm using wildfly 9, so that is Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}.

Comment: See my updates. I toned down my first answer and tried everything on EclipseLink, so I see why you had troubles.

Comment: How did you manage to get it to work for EclipseLink? I have the same issue as the OP. I also modified my schemas by hand, whilst I didn't get the issue at insert time, I still had issues when it came to fetch or update the data (basically the map is always empty when fetching and updates just add new records).